# Community profile not triggering email alert

Tags: community

I have one public community with it's profile which has:
Send email - checked
Access to all Order fields
Deliverability - All emails

I have one Workflow Rule to send an email alert whenever an Order is activated. If I do that manually with an Admin User it works but not with the community User.
I've put another Field Update action to see if the WFR was being activated, and it is.

So I guess there might be one permission that is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing the email alert to send the email using the OWD email, not currently user's email (which is the default).
Since the guest user does not have an email, the alert wasnt being sent.